# BotChat.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer.instance.onIsPlayingChanged is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure-cognitive-services, direct-line-botframework, speechsynthesizer

I want enable stop button on `SpeechSynthesizer` isplaying property is true. So I have used onIsPlayingChanged function. The function calling on change of isplaing property.

```
BotChat.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer.instance.onIsPlayingChanged = function(newValue, oldValue) {
    const musicStopButton = document.getElementsByClassName("music-stop")[0];
    if (newValue === true) {
        musicStopButton.classList.add("show");
    } else {
        musicStopButton.classList.remove("show");
    }
};
```

I have tried above mentioned code on more on. nothing is working. Please help me on this issue

Comment: Can you add the error details to check?

Comment: There's no error message. On change of _isplaying property, this event not triggered